# Can we make topological covers of $\mathbf{P}^1$ minus three points into schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, covering-spaces

Let $k=\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$. Fix a finite closed subset $B\subset \mathbf{P}^1_k$. Let $X$ be a "nice" topological space and suppose that there is a continuous morphism $f:X\to \mathbf{P}^1_k-B$.

Assume that $f$ is a covering space topologically of degree $d<\infty$.

Can we give  $X$ the structure of a smooth affine curve such that $f:X\to \mathbf{P}^1_k-B$  becomes a finite etale morphism?

This is possible if $k=\mathbf{C}$.

Comment: What is the topology on $P^1_k \setminus B$ for your covering space ?

Comment: I consider $U:=\mathbf{P}^1_k\backslash B$ with the open subscheme structure. Although this isn't clear from the way I wrote it, I assume that $B$ is closed.

Comment: If you us the Zariski topology, then the covering is just trivial : $X$ is a disjoint union of $d$ copies of the base space (exercise :)).

Comment: Doesn't $\mathbf{P}^1-\{0,1,\infty\}$ have many non-trivial finite etale covers?

Comment: But the étale covers in algebraic geometry are not topological covers.

Comment: What a silly mistake of mine!! I was confused because the analytification of an etale cover is a topological cover.